# C treats char as a letter, not a one-byte integer

Tags: c, string, char

So let's say I need to take a number from user input, only from 0 to 9. Everything else is out of bounds.

I figure this number ought to fit within a one-byte integer, a char (0-255). Typically I see people use int here, but that's wasteful, isn't it? 32 bits (or whatever the implementation is) just to store the numbers 0-9?

What I find is that the code below (which uses shorts) works, but when I change it to use only a one-byte **char**, not a two-byte **short**, it begins to treat the user input as a string, so if a user enters 235, convert() no longer catches the error condition. It just returns the first digit of their number.

I'm aware that C implements strings as arrays of characters. Is there a way to use char to represent a single one-byte integer without treating it like a string? Should I just abandon the idea of using one-byte integers as numbers?

(I shortened this to test for 0-1, not 0-9, for the sake of brevity)

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *convert(short digit)
{
    char *english;
    switch (digit) {
    case 0:
        english = "zero";
        break;
    case 1:
        english = "one";
        break;
    default:
        english = "";
        break;
    }
    return english;
}

void main(void)
{
    short digit;
    char *english;
    printf("Enter a digit between 0 and 9: ");
    scanf("%hu", &digit);
    english = convert(digit);
    if (english[0] == '\0') {
    printf("\nYour number was invalid\n");
    } else {
    printf("\nYou entered the number %s\n", english);
    }
}
```

Update:

Here's the attempted version that accepts a char, not a short:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *convert(char digit)
{
    char *english;

    switch (digit) {
        case 0:
            english = "zero";
            break;
        case 1:
            english = "one";
            break;
        default:
            english = "";
            break;
    }
    return english;
}

void main(void)
{
    char digit;
    char *english;
    printf("Enter a digit between 0 and 9: ");
    scanf("%c", &digit);
    english = convert(digit);
    if (english[0] == '\0') {
        printf("\nYour number was invalid\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nYou entered the number %s\n", english);
    }
}
```

The observed behavior of the above is that any number entered is flagged as invalid.

Comment: "What I find is that the code below (which uses shorts) works, but when I change it to use only a one-byte char, not a two-byte short, it begins to treat the user input as a string, so if a user enters 235, convert() no longer catches the error condition. It just returns the first digit of their number."

Please post code that shows how you've attempted to do this. You've most likely got the wrong type (char*) instead of (char) or the wrong scanf token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `scanf("%c", &digit);` to `scanf("%hhd", &digit);`

`%c` is the specifier to read a character and store that character. `%d` is the specifier to read a number written as base-10 digits and convert that to an integer (with `hh` meaning to write the answer into a `char`).

It is nothing to do with how "C treats a char", it is to do with how you instructed the `scanf` function to treat its input.  A `char` *is* a one-byte integer.

Also, your code `short digit; scanf("%hu", &digit);` is incorrect; `%hu` is the specifier for `unsigned short`. Either use `%hd` or `unsigned short digit;`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to use `scanf` to input a one byte integer. If you mean your format string is `"%c"` this is an (ascii) character, not a one byte integer. If you wish to treat it as a one byte integer you need to convert it yourself. `c = c - '0';` will work find if a value 0-9 was provided.

If instead your intention is to scan in values within the full 8 bit range, you must scan in at least a short and you can take the lower 8 bits if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

> Typically I see people use int here, but that's wasteful, isn't it? 32 bits (or whatever the implementation is) just to store the numbers 0-9?

Using `char` instead of `short` won't save space and will be most likely counter productive in most cases.

For function parameters, the compiler will generate code that passes `char`s as `int`s (otherwise the stack will become unaligned which generates a fault on most platforms and severly slows down the machine on most others.

For most arithmetic operations on `char`s, the compiler will be forced to do integer promotion (extend `char` to `int`, do the operation and truncate the result).

Comment: Well, goddamn, there's no point in optimizing at all, is there. Are there are any reference documents relating to this kind of "let the compilter optimize itself"

Comment: Arithmetic operations on chars are *guaranteed* to be performed on `int` instead, and the result reduced back down to store in the `char` if you assign the result to `char`.

Comment: According to the specs (hope I have them right), compilers don't need to do that in _every_ case, but _must_ return the same result as if they would (that's why I wrote "most").